# Is it possible to execute "begin transaction" when connected to MS SQL server with Oracle's SQL Developer?

Tags: sql-server, oracle-sql-developer

I am using Oracle's SQL Developer to execute SQL statements on an MS SQL Server instance. Apparently, SQL Developer recognizes specific Oracle related keywords such as `begin`. Thus, when I try to execute `begin transaction`, SQL Developer will give me the error *Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'begin'.*.

So, is there something I can tweak in order to be able to execute such a statement?